# SVG picture not showing in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, svg, react-hooks

Can someone help me understand why this svg is not rendering into my screen, please?

```
  const fireee = this.state.h.map(e => { 
          <SvgUri
    width="10%"
    height="10%"
    uri="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nomics-api/static/images/currencies/btc.svg"
  /> }
      )

      return (    

<View>
{fireee}
</View>
```

Comment: <Image probz does not support svg files whilst the svg module in react native does

Comment: const fireee = this.state.h.map((e) => {
      if (e.logo_url.includes('svg')) {
        console.log(e.logo_url);
        return (
          <SvgUri
    width="3%"
    height="3%"
    
    uri={e.logo_url}/>
        );
      } else {
        return (
           <Image
            source={{ uri: e.logo_url }}
            style={{ width: 20, height: 20, left: '20%' }}
          />
        )
      }
    });

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<View>
  <SvgUri
    width="10%"
    height="10%"
    source={{ uri: "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nomics-api/static/images/currencies/btc.svg"}} 
  />
</View>
```

Comment: yeah i wanted it to work using the map as there will be multiple

Comment: you can store the mapped link to a variable and use FlatList to show your content

Answer (score 0):

```
const fireee = this.state.h.map((e) => {
      if (e.logo_url.includes('svg')) {
        console.log(e.logo_url);
        return (
          <SvgUri
    width="3%"
    height="3%"
    
    uri={e.logo_url}/>
        );
      } else {
        return (
           <Image
            source={{ uri: e.logo_url }}
            style={{ width: 20, height: 20, left: '20%' }}
          />
        )
      }
    });
```

need to create a conditional to treat svg and png different